# Did Stefan Zweig tell this anecdote in The World of Yesterday"?

Tags: german-language, quote-source, stefan-zweig, the-world-of-yesterday

Many years ago I read [The World of Yesterday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Yesterday) by Stefan Zweig. I believe that in this book there was the following, real-life story: Shortly before the outbreak of World War II several intellectuals, including the author, discussed whether or not a big war (like World War I) was possible. They agreed it wasn't because they believed that peoples of Europe were too tired from the first war to want a second one.

I tried to find the exact quote in the [Kindle edition](https://www.amazon.de/Die-Welt-Gestern-Stefan-Zweig-ebook/dp/B00CF3YN6C/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=), but couldn't.

Did Stefan Zweig write this? If yes, where (book, chapter)?

Comment: *Nun hatte ich zehn Jahre des neuen Jahrhunderts gelebt, Indien, ein Stück von Amerika und Afrika gesehen; mit einer neuen, wissenderen Freude begann ich auf unser Europa zu blicken. Nie habe ich unsere alte Erde mehr geliebt als in diesen letzten Jahren vor dem Ersten Weltkrieg, nie mehr auf Europas Einigung gehofft, nie mehr an seine Zukunft geglaubt als in dieser Zeit, da wir meinten, eine neue Morgenröte zu erblicken [...]* This is similar to what you describe, but it's about the first world war (World of Yesterday, chapter 10).

Comment: I've skimmed through the chapters 17 and 18 as well [from Project Guttenberg](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/die-welt-von-gestern-6858/18) and couldn't find that sentiment. Zweig claims he knew from '33 on that war was inevitable.

Comment: @Narusan Thanks. Maybe it's time for me to re-read this wonderful book.

Comment: @Narusan I wonder if either you or Franz Drollig could turn your findings into an answer?